# How do I override a method from within an inherited method in Python

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, inheritance, overriding

I'm rather new to class inheritance and need some assistance

I have a problem, where I want to override a parent class method, after it has been called from another inherited parent class method.

The basic concept looks something like this:

```
class Parent:

    """Parent class, that defines the logical workflow"""

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def outer_method(self):
        # This method is called from the sub_classes
        # everything in here is the same for all sub_classes
        self.__inner_method(self)

    def __inner_method(self):
        # This method is called from self.outer_method()
        # Everything in here will be handled differently by each sub_class
        # And will therefore be overridden
        pass

class Child(Parent):

    """Sub_class, that inherits from the Parent class"""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def __inner_method(self):
        # this should override Parent.__inner_method()
        super().__inner_method()
        print('Do some custom operations unique to this Sub_class')
```

The idea here is, that the `Child` class calls `outer_method` which then calls `__inner_method`, which I want to be overridden by the child class.

But that doesn't work.
When I run this script,

```
def main():
    MyChild = Child()
    MyChild.outer_method()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

what happens is that instead of calling `Child.__inner_method()`, `Parent.__inner_method()` is called.

How can I get the Child class to override the inner method of the parent class, after it has been called from the inherited outer method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the problem is the name you choose, python apply an special treatment to a class members if its name start with `__` but doesn't end with that, called [`name mangling`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html?#private-variables), the reason it does that is in order to get python version of private variables/methods, so your `__inner_method` got renamed to `_Parent__inner_method` as result and any call to `__inner_method` withing the parent class gets modify to be a call to this renamed method, and because the same happens to the child class its end with a `_Child__inner_method` of it own which of course messed up with the inheritance mechanism if this isn't desired.

The solution is simple, rename all `__inner_method` to `_inner_method`.

A single `_` is the convention for private stuff when you don't want the name mangling, with `__` is for when you want it to be extra private if you will...